# Valor identidicador JQuery a variable PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Buen dia amigos.

Dispongo el siguiente codigo js en el cual extraigo datos desde la base de datos mediante ajax, y logro obtener mis datos a mi formulario mediante su atributo id.

```
 $(".btnEditarTicket").click(function(){

    var idTicket = $(this).attr("idTicket");

    var datos = new FormData();

    datos.append("idTicket",idTicket);

    $.ajax({

        url:"ajax/tickets.ajax.php",
        method :"POST",
        data:datos,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(respuesta){

            console.log("respuesta", respuesta);

            $("#IdeditarTitulo").val(respuesta["id"]);
            $("#editarTitulo").val(respuesta["titulo"]);
            $("#editarDescripcion").val(respuesta["descripcion"]);
            $("#editarUserid").val(respuesta["user_id"]);

            $("#editarProject").val(respuesta["project_id"]);
            $("#editarProject").html(respuesta["project_id"]);

            $("#editarCategory").val(respuesta["category_id"]);
            $("#editarCategory").html(respuesta["category_id"]);

        }

    }); 
})
```

Hasta aqui me devuelve los datos correctamente ahora lo que quiero es que el valor de `$("#editarProject").val(respuesta["project_id"]);` y de `$("#editarCategory").val(respuesta["category_id"]);` los pueda tomar como variables de php, que opcion podria utilizar. Alguna sugerencia se los agredeceria.

Comment: no puedes convertir valores del js a php, para que los quieres usar como variables php?

Comment: debes agregar los valores de esas variables a tu variable **datos** y recibirlos en tu archivo php

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar por qué motivo los quieres como variables de PHP? No le veo ninguna justificación válida. Acabaste de venir del servidor, ¿por qué vuelves a él? Es como si haces un viaje de `n` kilómetros y luego recuerdas que olvidaste hacer o recoger algo, vas a tener que hacer una inversión (en recursos) para volver de donde acabas de venir y vas a perder tiempo, habrá quizá molestias a causa de tus olvidos, etc.

Comment: Supongo que la razón es porque el ID viene de una consulta y quiere hacer otra operación con el resultado de ese ID.